# Finding a probability using PDF of uniform distribution

Tags: probability

If two points $A$ and $B$ are chosen from a circle with radius $a$, such that the perpendicular distance from the centre of the chord to $AB$ is uniformed distributed over $(0,a)$, what is $P(AB≥a)$?

If $d$ = perpendicular distance, I have $d \sim U(0,a)$

I suspect that I must relate $d$ in my question but I'm unsure as to how.

$1 - P(AB≤a)$ is equivalent to what I want to find, and now I need an integral $$P\left(AB\le a\right)=\int_{0}^{a}f_{a}\left(A\right)da$$ except I know its probably not in terms of $a$, I just up that there to show something vaguely like what I'm looking for. I know the top endpoint is $a$ because when $AB = a$, I can find when $AB$ is less than $a$.

Also I note that when $AB = a$, $d = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$, which is basically the answer disregarding the $a$.

Can someone help me synthesize all these points to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be saying $$AB \ge a \iff d \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$$

Since $d \sim U[0,a]$ with density $\frac1a$ and $\mathbb P\left(d \le x\right) =\frac xa$ for $0 \le x \le a$, this means

$$\mathbb P(AB \ge a)=  \mathbb P\left(d \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: what is $x$ you have chosen?

Comment: and is integration not needed?

Comment: @user71207 If you insist, $\int\limits_{y=0}^x \frac1a\,dy=\frac{x}{a}$ but this is obvious from a uniform distribution.  You want the probability for $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$

Comment: Ah yes sorry, thanks this was what I was looking for